# Mismatch of retention results from firebase and BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I calculated the retention i BigQuery with code bellow. Code was taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/sbrissenden/cab9bd3a043f1879ded605cba5005457). But this code is giving me different retention then the retention already calculated in firebase. Number of users calculated in BigQuery is always smaller.

What is the difference between this two approaches? Is there a way to get the same result in BigQuery as it is in Firebase?

```
#standardSQL
####################################################################
# PART 1: Cohort of New Users starting on SEPT 1
####################################################################
WITH 
new_user_cohort AS (  
  SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id as new_user_id
  FROM 
    `projectId.analytics_YOUR_TABLE.events_*`
  WHERE
   event_name = 'first_open' AND
   #geo.country = 'France' AND
   FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d", TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), DAY, "Etc/GMT+8")) = '20180901' AND
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180830' AND '20180902'),
num_new_users AS (
  SELECT count(*) as num_users_in_cohort  FROM new_user_cohort
),

####################################################################
# PART 2: Engaged users from Sept 1 cohort
####################################################################
engaged_user_by_day AS (  
  SELECT 
    FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), DAY, "Etc/GMT+8")) as event_day, COUNT (DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) as num_engaged_users
  FROM 
    `projectId.analytics_YOUR_TABLE.events_*` INNER JOIN new_user_cohort on new_user_id = user_pseudo_id 
  WHERE
    event_name = 'user_engagement' AND
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180830' AND '20180907'
  GROUP BY (event_day)
)

####################################################################
# PART 3: Daily Retention = [Engaged Users / Total Users]
####################################################################
SELECT event_day, num_engaged_users, num_users_in_cohort, ROUND((num_engaged_users / num_users_in_cohort), 3) as retention_rate
  FROM engaged_user_by_day CROSS JOIN num_new_users
ORDER BY (event_day)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "always smaller"? Can you add some example results of both for the same period?

Comment: I started on day 2021-09-21.  In big query with above code I get day0 retention 1453 users, day 1 retention 662 and day 2 retention 441. Meanwhile if Firebase Analytics for the same day I get  day 0 retention 1481, day 1 retention 680 and day 2 retention 452. And by always smaller I mean that even if I check another date, the user count will be smaller in BigQuery then in FireBase

Comment: And even more frustrating I went to Google Analytics and tried to replicate this and got a third different result.

Comment: I can see that the code does consider  exact time zone. Are you sure that all work the same time zone?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I don't believe timezones are the problem. I also tested multiple timezones and I never got a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that that analytics is using [sampling](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9371379#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) and in my report inside analytics it only uses 0.2% of the data.

In firebase I noticed that they removed retention tab (at least in my case). But I think there sampling was also used.